# How to Identify working FOLDER in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm retrieveing the current path with:

```
Dim paths As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath
```

Which returns something like `/VHP/hmo.aspx`

What I need to narrow down is the FOLDER (VHP).  How do I remove the `/` before it and the `/filename` after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Dim paths As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath
Dim dir as String= Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(path))
```

**UPDATE**
According to your code, you should do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
  Dim strFileNamePath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath))

  ''some how grab the working folder name here 
  If strFileNamePath = "xyz" Then 
  'do this 
  Else If strFileNamePath = "abc" then 
   'do this' 
  End If
End Sub
```

Notice how I changed `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` for `HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath`

Comment: I realized that I had written my initial answer in C# :D

Comment: When I used your suggestion, I get "swiggly" lines under "Path.GetDirectoryName",
say, " 'GetDirectoryName' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.

Am I missing an "Imports..." on my codebehind?

Comment: @BeckaBear Yes, you are missing `using System.IO;`

Comment: -- still no luck even after adding Imports System.IO  (same error)
I'm using .NET Framerwork 3.5 if that makes a difference.  Things that "should work" just don't... *sigh*

Comment: @BeckaBear because according to the error, you are trying to call GetDirectoryName on a Label. Post your whole code and I'll point exactly what you need to do.

Comment: 'Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
Dim strFileNamePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath 
''some how grab the working folder name here 
If strFileNamePath = "xyz" Then 
'do this 
Else If strFileNamePath = "abc" then 
'do this 
End If'

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your help. What you gave me (updated code) returned the full path c:/_root/web/folder/vhp/hmo.aps  - more than what I need.  BUT - you did help me to come up with this:
Dim Dir As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath
        Dim strFileNamePath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Dir)
        Path.Text = strFileNamePath

and this returned "/VHP"  and I know how to remove the "/"  THANK YOU AGAIN for help us little people!